# Including a module swallows its type

Tags: types, module, ocaml

I have the following:

A `Person` module type with methods to get the first and last name:

```
module type Person = sig
  type t
  val first : t -> string
  val last : t -> string
end
```

A `PersonUtils` functor to extend `Person` with a `name` function:

```
module PersonUtils (Person: Person) : sig
  type t
  val name : t -> string
end = struct
  include Person
  let name p = Person.first p ^ " " ^ Person.last p
end
```

and a `Main` module as follows:

```
module Main : sig
  type t
  val name : t -> string
end = struct
  include PersonUtils(struct
      type t = {
        first: string;
        last: string;
      }

      let first p = p.first
      let last p = p.last
    end)
end
```

In `Main`, I would like to add an additional `loud_first_name` function: so I add the following to the signature and module:

```
module Main : sig
  type t
  val name : t -> string

  (* New *)
  val loud_first_name : t -> string
end = struct
  include PersonUtils(struct
      type t = {
        first: string;
        last: string;
      }

      let first p = p.first
      let last p = p.last
    end)

  (* New *)
  let loud_first_name p = String.uppercase p.first
end
```

However, it appears that `loud_first_name` no longer knows the structure of my type `t`, so I am left with the error `Unbound record field first`.

My question is: how can I create methods like `loud_first_name` such that they can still access my record fields? I attempted to move my `t` type up a level, but had trouble using it in the argument of my functor.

```
module Main : sig
  type t
  val name : t -> string
  val loud_first_name : t -> string
end = struct
  type t_ = {
    first: string;
    last: string;
  }

  include PersonUtils(struct
      type t = t_

      let first p = p.first
      let last p = p.last
    end)

  (* Signature mismatch:
       ...
       Values do not match:
         val loud_first_name : t_ -> string
       is not included in
         val loud_first_name : t -> string
  *)
  let loud_first_name p = String.uppercase p.first
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a combination of `type nonrec t = t` (thanks [Étienne Millon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7443386/%C3%89tienne-millon)) and including the module *with a signature* fixed my issue.

```
module type PUSig = sig
  type t
  val name : t -> string
end

module PersonUtils (Person: Person) : PUSig with type t = Person.t = struct
  include Person
  let name p = Person.first p ^ " " ^ Person.last p
end

module Main : sig
  type t = {
    first: string;
    last: string;
  }
  val loud_first_name : t -> string
end = struct
  type t = {
    first: string;
    last: string;
  }

  include (PersonUtils(struct
             type nonrec t = t
             let first p = p.first
             let last p = p.last
           end) : PUSig with type t := t)

  (* New *)
  let loud_first_name p = String.uppercase_ascii p.first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You must indicate in your signature that your type is the same, if you only indicate it in the structure, the information will be lost.

```
module PersonUtils (Person: Person) : sig
  type t = Person.t
  val name : t -> string
end
 = struct
  include Person
  let name p = Person.first p ^ " " ^ Person.last p
end
```

Another approach (wich I recommend) is to add a `with` clause to your module type declaration.

```
module PersonUtils (Person: Person) : sig
  type t
  val name : t -> string
end
with type t = Person.t
 = struct
  include Person
  let name p = Person.first p ^ " " ^ Person.last p
end
```

Though the information is not directly visible in the signature declaration, it allows you to separately declare your signature  and your functor:

```
module type Personutils_T = sig
  type t
  val name : t -> string
end

module PersonUtils (Person: Person) : Personutils_T
with type t = Person.t
 = struct
  include Person
  let name p = Person.first p ^ " " ^ Person.last p
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get rid of the signature mismatch in my last example. But is there any way to avoid `type t = t_`? If I inline `type t = { first: string; ... }` then my `loud_first_name` method is still unable to see its fields.

Comment: You can try `type nonrec t = t`. It will refer to the `t` in scope, not the one being defined.

Comment: Thanks @ÉtienneMillon! I didn't know about that syntax. Still, the module I'm including causes my type `t` to be a duplicate (and I get an error message). Perhaps I'm using `include` incorrectly?

Comment: Got it! `include`ing my module `: Sig with type t := t` fixes the issue along with `type nonrec t = t`. Thanks so much!